# error "The current path, user_info/, didn't match any of these."

Tags: python, django

Well, this question has been asked by many users, and I have tried some of the resolution provided in the query, but that doesn't seem to resolve my issue, maybe I am doing some other mistake.

I am trying to create a simple user registration/login/logout forms

SchoolnSkill ---Project name, and below is the SchoolnSkill/url details:-

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^user_info/', include('user_info.urls')),
]
```

user_info--App name, and the user_info/url details are below:-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   # url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^registration/', views.UserFormView, name='registration')
]
```

My views.py output is as below:-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.views import generic
from .models import Registration
from django.views import View
from .forms import UserForm

class UserFormView(View):
    #from_class = UserForm
    template_name = 'user_info/registration_form.html'

    #dispaly blank form, new user coming to the website
    def get(self, request):
        form = self.UserForm(None)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.UserForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
```

form.py content as below:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget =forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password']
```

I am using below versions:

Python 3.6
Django 1.11.3
Spyder IDE

I am pretty sure that am doing something silly.
Please help.

below is the error message:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/user_info/
Using the URLconf defined in SchoolnSkill.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^user_info/ ^registration/ [name='registration']
The current path, user_info/, didn't match any of these.
```

Answer (score 2):

as you are using class based view you need to add `as_view` in the url

so

change this in `user_info` url to

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^registration/', views.UserFormView.as_view(), name='registration')
]
```

Comment: you cannot get a url like /user_info/ as you havent defined anything for that, the 1st url is commented out, so you need to go to /user_info/registration/ to get the registration page

Comment: ok, so there is some changes when I use user_info/registration. But I am getting attribute error, which is understandable. I am done with this query here. thanks a ton..